# remove NA from NumericVector in RCpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am a newbie to Rcpp (and a newbie to C++). I wrote a code using an example code here https://gist.github.com/kevinushey/4561281 to calculate row/col max/mix for matrices as follows:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <class T>
inline double do_max(T& x) {
  return max(x);
}

template <class T>
inline double do_min(T& x) {
  return min(x);
}

NumericVector colMaxsCpp(NumericMatrix& x) {
  int nRows = x.nrow();
  NumericVector out = no_init(nRows);

  for (int i=0; i<nRows;i++) {
    NumericMatrix::Row tmp = x(i,_);
    out[i]=do_max(tmp);
  }

  return out;
}

NumericVector colMinsCpp(NumericMatrix& x) {
  int nRows = x.nrow();
  NumericVector out = no_init(nRows);

  for (int i=0; i<nRows;i++) {
    NumericMatrix::Row tmp = x(i,_);
    out[i]=do_min(tmp);
  }

  return out;
}

NumericVector rowMaxsCpp(NumericMatrix& x) {
  int nCols = x.ncol();
  NumericVector out = no_init(nCols);

  for (int i=0; i<nCols;i++) {
    NumericMatrix::Column tmp = x(_,i);
    out[i]=do_max(tmp);
  }

  return out;
}

NumericVector rowMinsCpp(NumericMatrix& x) {
  int nCols = x.ncol();
  NumericVector out = no_init(nCols);

  for (int i=0; i<nCols;i++) {
    NumericMatrix::Column tmp = x(_,i);
    out[i]=do_min(tmp);
  }

  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector Max(NumericMatrix x, int dim) {
  if (dim==1) {
    return rowMaxsCpp(x);
  } else if (dim==2) {
    return colMaxsCpp(x);
  }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector Min(NumericMatrix x, int dim) {
  if (dim==1) {
    return rowMinsCpp(x);
  } else if (dim==2) {
    return colMinsCpp(x);
  }
}
```

I want to modify to code to handle `NA` in the `do_min` and `do_max` functions. The `do_min` and `do_max` functions use a `template` of a class.

I read on the web about `NA_REAL` and `NA_INTEGER` but these are specific to classes.

(a) Is there any generic `NA` available for a `template` of a class (such as in the example above)?

(b) Also, is there any function available that I can subset a variable `x` to only use non-`NA` elements, e.g. equivalent of `max(x[!is.na(x)])` or `min(x[!is.na(x)])` in `R` ?

(c) Finally, the code above has been written to handle a numeric `matrix`, but it seems to work even when an integer `matrix` has been supplied (albeit the output is converted to `numeric`). Why is this so?

Comment: There is a sugar function `na_omit`.

Comment: @Roland, great, thanks. I tried replacing `max(x)` with `max(na_omit(x))` but it didn't compile. Would it be possible for you to tell me how can I use it with `max(x)`?

Comment: Which version of Rcpp are you using? Your code compiles just fine if I do this.

Comment: @Roland, using `Rcpp 0.11.1`. Actually, the code compiled, but there were errors like "Line 70 control reaches end of non-void function"

Comment: That warning is normal with `g++` under suffcient warning levels. You need to insert an unconditional return a la `NumericVector NeverReached(1); return NeverReached;` to suppress it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks. it works now without the two warnings. I probably figured out the reason - the `else if` statement needed a final `else` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick ones:

a) Yes, there are but I am not sure they are vectorised. But some templated NA traits were added.

b) Yes as e.g. in

```
R> cppFunction('double mymax(NumericVector x) { \
                   IntegerVector x2 = wrap(na_omit(x)); \
                   return max(x2);}')
R> mymax(c(1L, 2L, NA, 4L))
[1] 4
R>
```

c) Integer always gets 'cast up' to Numeric at the cost of a copy.

@Roland already hinted at `na_omit`.  In b), somehow I need to help with a `wrap()` to generate an intermediate `SEXP` object.

Comment: I can compile and use `cppFunction('double mymax(NumericVector x) {return max(na_omit(x));}')` without problems.

Comment: @Roland, actually, my bad, the code did compile, but it gave me two warnings. Dirk gave me the answer to the warnings in his comment above